# How to install plm package?

Tags: r, installation, plm

Even after install `plm` package, I am getting the following error how to resolve this issue?

```
library(plm)
```

> Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘plm’ in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]):
> there is no package called ‘Rdpack’

Comment: What version of R are you running? [Rdpack is on CRAN](https://cran.r-project.org/package=Rdpack) so you can try installing that directly with `install.packages("Rdpack")`. How did you install `plm`? If you did `install.packages("plm")` it should have installed the dependencies for you.